# how to get array values of a node property in jcr

Tags: jcr, aem

Need help in getting the string[] values of node property??

for example I have a node image which has property "references" of type String[] . I need to get the first value of array.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Node, you can get the references property.  And then call getValues to the reference values.  From there, just take the first.  Something like

```
public String getFirstReference(Node node) throws RepositoryException {
  Property references = node.getProperty("references");     
  Value[] values = references.getValues();
  return values[0].getString();     
}
```

Comment: There are some useful examples of working with JCR on the jackrabbit [first hops](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/first-hops.html) page

Comment: If you are working with Sling in CQ5 you can adapt a Resource to a ValueMap or use the properties object in your JSPs.  e.g.  properties.get("references", String[].class)

Comment: @user2000633: the best way to think someone is to vote up their answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Property nProp = node.getProperty("references");
Value[] values = propertyNode.getValues();
for (Value v : values) {
    System.out.println("Property Name = "+nProp.getName()+" ; Property Value= "+v.getString());
}
```