# Get array values from node property with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, aem

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460843/how-to-get-array-values-of-a-node-property-in-jcr), but I need the equivalent in javascript.
I have a selectbox inside a multifield containing options with string array values.

**JCR Structure**

```
<multiField
    fieldLabel="Fields"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    cardinality="5"
    sling:resourceType="/apps/.../multifield"
    buttonName="Add Field"
    slideStyle="border">
    <field
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        name="./fields"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <selectBox
                        fieldLabel="Select Box"
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        name="./select"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <option1
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="Option 1"
                                value="['val1':'value 1','val2':'value 2','val3':'value 3']"/>
                            <option2
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="Option 2"
                                value="['val1':'value 1','val2':'value 2','val3':'value 3']"/>                                                                      
                        </items>
                    </selectBox>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </field>
</multiField>
```

I loop through the multifield with js

**JS File**

```
"use strict";
use(function() {
    return {
        data: JSON.parse(this.value)
    };
});
```

**HTML File**

```
<div data-sly-list.field="${properties['fields']}" data-sly-unwrap>
   <div data-sly-use.json="${'jsfile.js' @ value=field}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <div data-sly-list.input="${json.data.select}" data-sly-unwrap>
            <div data-sly-list.input="${json.data.inputField}" data-sly-unwrap>
                <div data-sly-use.attr="${'multivalues.js' @ value=input}" data-sly-unwrap>
                    ${attr.data}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is where I get stuck. I can't seem to loop through the array. I get `"[Ljava.lang.String;@6d100000"`

**multivalues.js**

```
"use strict";
use(function () {
    var attr = this.value.toString();
    return {
        data: JSON.stringify(attr)
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"['val1':'value 1','val2':'value 2','val3':'value 3']"` isn't a properly formatted Array. Here are examples of an array with Strings and Array with Objects:

```
return {
    dataString : JSON.parse('["alpha", "bravo"]'),
    dataObject : JSON.parse('[{"name" : "alpha", "age" : 20}, {"name" : "bravo", "age" : 25}]')
};
```

Then you can loop through them:

```
<div data-sly-use.logic="jsfile.js">
    <div data-sly-list.input="${logic.dataString}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <p>${input}</p>
    </div>

    <div data-sly-list.input="${logic.dataObject}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <p>${input.name}</p>
        <p>${input.age}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```